# Clicking the parent of an HTML select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot seem to click the parent of a `select` when it is disabled. I'm trying to allow the user to unlock inputs by clicking them, but it only works for `inputs`.

```js
    let $input = $('input')
    $input.parent().click(function() {
      $input.prop('disabled', false);
    })
    let $select = $('select')
    $select.parent().click(function() {
      $select.prop('disabled', false);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="parent">
      <input name="name" disabled placeholder="click me">
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <select name="thing" disabled>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clicking disabled select element doesn't trigger click or mousedown events on it's parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503746/clicking-disabled-select-element-doesnt-trigger-click-or-mousedown-events-on-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this style:

```
select[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

That will cause a disabled select to ignore the mouse, which allows its parent to capture the click instead.

**Snippet:**

```js
let $input = $('input');
$input.parent().click(function() {
  $input.prop('disabled', false);
});

let $select = $('select');
$select.parent().click(function() {
  $select.prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```css
select[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <input name="name" disabled placeholder="click me">
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <select name="thing" disabled>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
</div>
```